# Get value of custom field (wordpress)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to design a theme that let's the users input a custom field, which in turn changes the background-color of each separate post on the landing screen. The code I've got doesn't seem to work. Is there an other way to get the custom field for each post?

Custom field name: background

Value: #333

.

Here's what I've got:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'background', true); ?>
    <div class="section" style="background-color: <?php echo $background; ?>;">

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
    </div>

    <?php endwhile;

    else: 
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $background = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'background', true); ?>
    <div class="section" style="background-color: <?php echo $background; ?>;">

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
    </div>

    <?php endwhile;

    else: 
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Change variable $image to $background

Comment: Oh... it's that simple. Geez, I've been staring at this for the last hour or so. Thank you for this!